# Rails Arel complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I am trying to combine an arel query with a Product scope.

```
p  = Spree::Product.arel_table
p1 = Spree::ProductProperties.arel_table
p2 = p1.alias
query = p
 .join(p1)
   .on(p[:id].eq(p1[:product_id]))
     .where(p1[:property_id].eq(5)
       .and(p1[:value].eq("10 inches")))
 .join(p2)
   .on(p[:id].eq(p2[:product_id]))
     .where(p2[:property_id].eq(4)
       .and(p2[:value].eq("1400")))
```

Now the problem is that this results in error when I try to combine it with base_scope thats adds some other criteria. 
    base_scope.where(query)

> => "SELECT \"spree_products\".*
>   FROM \"spree_products\" WHERE \"spree_products\".\"deleted_at\" IS
>   NULL AND ((SELECT FROM \"spree_products\" INNER JOIN
>   \"spree_product_prop erties\" ON \"spree_products\".\"id\" =
>   \"spree_product_properties\".\"product_id\" INNER JOIN
>   \"spree_product_properties\" \"spree_product_properties_2\" ON
>   \"spree_product s\".\"id\" =
>   \"spree_product_properties_2\".\"product_id\" WHERE
>   \"spree_product_properties\".\"property_id\" = 5 AND
>   \"spree_product_properties\".\"value\" = '10 inches' AN D
>   \"spree_product_properties_2\".\"property_id\" = 4 AND
>   \"spree_product_properties_2\".\"value\" = '1400'))"

Is there a way to achieve that wihout going to plain sql?

Comment: it seems that the `or` clause should be between join operators here yes?

Comment: How do you define the `base scope`, what is the error message?

Comment: its from Spree. One solution that seems to work was to split join and where. So I added join_sources for join and removed .where. Then base_scope.joins(query_joins).where(query_conds) worked fine